# Edit timedate index conditionally, checking previous record in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, timestamp

I have some csv files containing data logged with a serial terminal software. Data are generated at a variable sample rate:

- normally 1 row every 10 seconds
- in case of events, many strings per second are generated 
  See example:

  2019-01-04 12:39:40,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2048,2048

  2019-01-04 12:39:50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2048,2048

  2019-01-04 12:40:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2048,2048

  2019-01-04 12:40:09,92,20,306,302,0,0,0,0,2548,1956

  2019-01-04 12:40:09,112,24,306,302,0,0,0,0,2626,1923

  2019-01-04 12:40:09,136,32,306,302,0,0,0,0,2688,1884

  2019-01-04 12:40:09,156,40,306,302,0,0,0,0,2752,1839

  2019-01-04 12:40:09,180,48,306,302,0,0,0,0,2795,1809

  2019-01-04 12:40:09,200,60,306,302,0,0,0,0,2815,1773

Timestamp is added by terminal software using PC system time as source.
Unfortunately terminal software doesn't add milliseconds to timestamp, so, when importing csv to dataframe, I have multiple records with the same timestamp. 
How can I check if there are contiguous records with the same timestamp, and, in that case, add a timedelta of *n* milliseconds to records within the same second?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter per groups, convert to milisecond timedeltas with [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and add to `DatetimeIndex`:

```
print (df)
                       a    b    c    d  e  f  g  h     i     j
0                                                              
2019-01-04 12:39:11    0    0    0    0  0  0  0  0  2048  2048
2019-01-04 12:39:21    0    0    0    0  0  0  0  0  2048  2048
2019-01-04 12:39:31    0    0    0    0  0  0  0  0  2048  2048
2019-01-04 12:39:40    0    0    0    0  0  0  0  0  2048  2048
2019-01-04 12:39:50    0    0    0    0  0  0  0  0  2048  2048
2019-01-04 12:40:00    0    0    0    0  0  0  0  0  2048  2048
2019-01-04 12:40:09   92   20  306  302  0  0  0  0  2548  1956
2019-01-04 12:40:09  112   24  306  302  0  0  0  0  2626  1923
2019-01-04 12:40:09  136   32  306  302  0  0  0  0  2688  1884
2019-01-04 12:40:09  156   40  306  302  0  0  0  0  2752  1839
2019-01-04 12:40:09  180   48  306  302  0  0  0  0  2795  1809
2019-01-04 12:40:09  200   60  306  302  0  0  0  0  2815  1773
2019-01-04 12:40:09  216   68  306  302  0  0  0  0  2826  1736
2019-01-04 12:40:09  232   80  306  302  0  0  0  0  2817  1715
2019-01-04 12:40:09  244   88  306  302  0  0  0  0  2804  1665
2019-01-04 12:40:09  256  100  306  302  0  0  0  0  2756  1636

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-04 12:39:11', '2019-01-04 12:39:21',
               '2019-01-04 12:39:31', '2019-01-04 12:39:40',
               '2019-01-04 12:39:50', '2019-01-04 12:40:00',
               '2019-01-04 12:40:09', '2019-01-04 12:40:09',
               '2019-01-04 12:40:09', '2019-01-04 12:40:09',
               '2019-01-04 12:40:09', '2019-01-04 12:40:09',
               '2019-01-04 12:40:09', '2019-01-04 12:40:09',
               '2019-01-04 12:40:09', '2019-01-04 12:40:09'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=0, freq=None)
```

---

```
df.index += pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='ms')
print (df)
                           a    b    c    d  e  f  g  h     i     j
2019-01-04 12:39:11.000    0    0    0    0  0  0  0  0  2048  2048
2019-01-04 12:39:21.000    0    0    0    0  0  0  0  0  2048  2048
2019-01-04 12:39:31.000    0    0    0    0  0  0  0  0  2048  2048
2019-01-04 12:39:40.000    0    0    0    0  0  0  0  0  2048  2048
2019-01-04 12:39:50.000    0    0    0    0  0  0  0  0  2048  2048
2019-01-04 12:40:00.000    0    0    0    0  0  0  0  0  2048  2048
2019-01-04 12:40:09.000   92   20  306  302  0  0  0  0  2548  1956
2019-01-04 12:40:09.001  112   24  306  302  0  0  0  0  2626  1923
2019-01-04 12:40:09.002  136   32  306  302  0  0  0  0  2688  1884
2019-01-04 12:40:09.003  156   40  306  302  0  0  0  0  2752  1839
2019-01-04 12:40:09.004  180   48  306  302  0  0  0  0  2795  1809
2019-01-04 12:40:09.005  200   60  306  302  0  0  0  0  2815  1773
2019-01-04 12:40:09.006  216   68  306  302  0  0  0  0  2826  1736
2019-01-04 12:40:09.007  232   80  306  302  0  0  0  0  2817  1715
2019-01-04 12:40:09.008  244   88  306  302  0  0  0  0  2804  1665
2019-01-04 12:40:09.009  256  100  306  302  0  0  0  0  2756  1636
```

Comment: It's definitely what I need. Thanks.